# Removing elements from the pandas column if they do not contained in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have a list like this

```
certificates = [ISO9001, ISO203, CE2234]
```

and dataframe like this:

```
company_certificates
[ISO303, ISO9001]
[GlobalGAP12, ISO203]
[EuroGAP]
```

I want to remove the elements from company_certificates if they are not contained in certificates list. I know I can do something like this:

```
df['company_certificates'] = df['company_certificates'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in certificates])
```

Final output is:

```
company_certificates
[ISO9001]
[ISO203]
[]
```

But I need more efficient way of doing it given my dataframe is huge. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
data = {'company_certificates': [['ISO303', 'ISO9001'], ['GlobalGAP12', 'ISO203'], ['EuroGAP']]}
data['company_certificates'] *= 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
certificates = ['ISO9001', 'ISO203', 'CE2234']

# 3.1 s ± 134 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit
c2 = df['company_certificates'].tolist()
c1set = frozenset(certificates)
df['match'] = [[n for n in lst if n in c1set] for lst in c2]

# 4.32 s ± 578 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit
df['match'] = df['company_certificates'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in certificates])

# 7.23 s ± 616 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit
df['match'] = df['company_certificates'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(certificates)))     

# 9.43 s ± 913 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit
df['match'] = df['company_certificates'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y in x, certificates)))

# 32 s ± 2.11 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
mask = ~df['company_certificates'].explode().isin(certificates).reset_index() \
               .groupby('index').any()['company_certificates']
df.loc[mask,'company_certificates'] = [[]*mask.sum()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for each item of a list to be present in `certificates` list. And create a mask for rows in which at least one is present. Then replace values in that rows by the empty list

```
>>> mask = ~df['company_certificates'].explode().isin(certificates) \
              .groupby(level=0).any()
>>> mask
index
0    False
1    False
2     True

>>> df.loc[mask,'company_certificates'] = [[]*mask.sum()]
>>> df
    company_certificates
0      [ISO303, ISO9001]
1  [GlobalGAP12, ISO203]
2                     []
```